# What is default api rate limit of braintree?

Tags: braintree, braintree-sandbox

What is default api rate limit of brain tree?
Because after very requests in a time period I am getting 403(Too many request) exception.

Answer (score 0):

Raised when requests associated with your account reach unsafe levels. We may limit API resources by merchant if activity risks negative impact to other merchants.

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/exceptions/node#too-many-requests-error